# Contrary of "As its/their name indicates"

Tags: expressions, antonyms

In English we sometimes use the expression "*As its/their name indicates*" to express the fact that the name of a concept/object/etc. bears part of its meaning, [e.g.](http://cds.cern.ch/record/429855/files/0003083.pdf):

> As their name indicates, supernovae are discovered in the sky as
>   “new stars” (-novae) of exceptionally high brightness (super-).

How would you say in a similar fashion that the name is a misnomer?

For example:

> We are going to use logistic *regression*, which as its name does
>   not indicate is a *classification* model.

I would like to replace "which as its name does not indicate" by some expression that underlines the fact that the name is a misnomer, not just uninformative.

Comment: Not knowing what *logistic regression* is, I'm not sure if I get your question correctly. Are you looking for *despite that* (as many below have answered) because the term **suggests otherwise than stated**? Or, perhaps, are you looking for something implying that the term used is **neither** telling us what it means **nor** telling us the opposite?

Comment: @KonradViltersten First option:  the term suggests otherwise than stated. "logistic regression" is a misleading term, because regression is not classification. Yet, for historical reason, "logistic regression" is still being used.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would use [despite](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/despite):

> We are going to use logistic regression, which, despite its name, is a classification model.

Comment: I was about to add another suggestion "though its name suggests otherwise", but I saw this answer first. I believe this ("despite its name") is much more idiomatic.

Comment: Alternatively, "*in spite of*" if it seems that the either the name or the behavior are intentionally opposite.

Comment: We always forget about the most obvious, simple choice!

Answer (score 7):

I would put it thus:

> We are going to use logistic regression, which is, **quite contrary to what its name suggests**, a classification model.

Or we could use the word *[counterintuitive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/counterintuitive)*:

> We are going to use logistic regression, **which is a counterintuitive name for what is in fact** a classification model.

In place of *counterintuitive*, one could also use the adjectives *[misleading](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misleading)* and *unlikely*.

Or:

> We are going to use logistic regression, which is a classification model, **as its name fails to indicate**.
>
> We are going to use logistic regression, which is a classification model actually, **although its name fails to [put that across](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_across)**.

In place of *fails*, one could place *neglects*.

Comment: I like "misleading" as in: "We are going to use logistic regression. The name is misleading, since it's in fact a *classification* model.

Answer (score 3):

I like CopperKettle's suggestions. I think I would write it like this myself:

> We are going to use logistic regression, which unlike its name suggests, is actually a classification model.

Comment: This sounds a bit odd to my ears.  Are you a native speaker, and could this be a regionalism from your area?

Comment: @David, my native language is Australian English, so it shouldn't be substantially different to yours, my Kiwi friend. I couldn't find "(un)like its name suggests" in the COCA or BNC corpora. "Like its name suggests" however is very common in Google Books, and "unlike its name suggests" is not uncommon.

Comment: Yeah, if I read it in an Australian accent, it makes slightly more sense :-) It's certainly not something I'd ever say though.

Comment: I'm British and this does sound a bit odd. Not "wrong" in the grammatical sense, but not something I think I'd be likely to say.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that the problem with  most of these suggestions is that the term "logistic regression" does not have an evident surface meaning at all, and in that sense is not  obviously problematic.    I would say something like: "We will look at a statistical technique which predicts whether an individual has some property or not and which is known, a bit obscurely, as logistic regression"

Comment: "Regression" does have a meaning, or rather meanings (there's regressing to childhood and regressing to a mean), and none of those meanings have anything to do with classification. But +1 for "a bit obscurely".

Answer (score 2):

[There is a word that means exactly this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11422/what-is-a-catchy-word-that-means-non-self-descriptive):

> **[heterological](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heterological)**
> (grammar) Of an adjective, not describing itself.

It's [constructed as the logical counterpart/antonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grelling%E2%80%93Nelson_paradox) of [*autological*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterological), "a word expressing a property which it also possesses itself."

However, this is a pretty rare word, and not all dictionaries list it. So in actual practice, you're better off using some derivative of "contrary".

> We are going to use logistic regression, which, contrary to what its name indicates, is a classification model.
>
> We are going to use the self-contradictorily named "logistic regression", which is a classification model.

Answer (score 2):

> We are going to use the { **ill-named** | **poorly named** | **ineptly named** ... } logistic *regression*, which is **actually** a *classification* model.

Here, **bold** mark the words that work together to express the speaker's opinion about the name. *Italics* indicate the spoken emphasis: in a contrastive sentence, the elements being compared are stressed. Here, from the emphasis we know that "regression" is being held against "classification" (and not, say, "model"), which is important.

In place of "ill-named" or "poorly named", we can use **"so-called"**, which is less boldly critical of the naming, yet still calls the naming into question, or at least calls attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would [omit needless words](http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk5.html) and let the facts speak for themselves:

> We are going to use logistic regression, a classification model.

or,

> We are going to use logistic regression as our classification model.

Comment: Obviously, OP feels that making a remark on the naming isn't needless. If people are new to the material, it may help them to draw attention to any naming quirks in the domain so that they avoid confusion. If something called regression really isn't regression at all, it is worth pointing out.  You would hardly want to introduce "linear programming", which is a computer science topic, without making it clear that it has nothing to do with software development.

Comment: @Kaz The difference is pointed out by "*, a classification model.*"

Comment: Only to a listener who is "tuned in" to naming issues.